# How does Tomcat manage sessions?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

As I restarts tomcat container my application should go to index page( or login page) if I stop tomcat but instead it allows me to go to that view . It only redirects to index when I remove tomcat from eclipse and recreate tomcat server and start.
How does tomcat manage session that I have created in previous server start ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default tomcat configuration is to persist the session state to disk and reload it on next start. From the tomcat documentation [1]:

> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down normally and restarted, or when an
>   application reload is triggered, the standard Manager implementation
>   will attempt to serialize all currently active sessions to a disk file
>   located via the pathname attribute. All such saved sessions will then
>   be deserialized and activated (assuming they have not expired in the
>   mean time) when the application reload is completed.

This is configurable and can be disabled:

```
Every web application by default has standard manager implementation configured, and it performs session persistence across restarts. To disable this persistence feature, create a Context configuration file for your web application and add the following element there:

<Manager pathname="" />
```

[1] The official documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence